# How to set the min-height across all the browser

Tags: css

my problem is that i need to give below min-height to set in different browsers

```
>min-height: 154px in firefox
>min-height: 180px in chrome
>min-height: 135px in opera
```

is there any code which give me generic solution for that.
or trick like -moz- and -webkit- anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to fix your CSS so you won't need to do that. This browsers should display your page almost identically, so you are probably doing something very weird.

With that being said, the easiest solution (if you absolutely, positively) need to do this is to use CSS hacks to target different browsers. See here for examples: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/

Comment: yes this is a good solution but i need something generic solution.by the way thanks for your answer.